# PHP if statement to display colour based on database?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Is it possible to create a PHP if statement that will display a certain colour based on my database?

I want to create a PHP table that will list all the ports currently open in work. The data will be stored in a MySQL database. Basically if the port is open green will display in the table and if it's not open then red will be displayed.

Is this possible to do in PHP?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Next question please.

Comment: awesome now how would I do this? :)

Comment: You can do this by coding

Comment: Add colors' row in database and select from it

Comment: @SabaTandashvili better store/get the status in/from the db and if else the colour accordingly.

Comment: You might want to check the Help section, this will be closed as off-topic or too broad very shortly I'd imagine : http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Do you know how to change a table cell's colour in HTML?

Comment: Thank you both I'll try these

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:

*Yes*

**How?**

Let us say, your table structure is as follows:

```
-------------------------
Port             |Open
-------------------------
1111             |1

2222             |0

1212             |1
-------------------------
```

You could acheive what you are trying to do as:

```
//connect to database

//fetch all records

$records //Lets say this contains all the records
echo '<table>';
foreach($records as $record){
   echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<th>'. $record["port"] .'</th>';
    echo displayOpen($record);
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';


function displayOpen($record){
  if($record["isOpen"] == 1){
    return '<th style="color:green">open</th>';
  }else{
    return '<th style="color:red">close</th>';
  }
}
```

This should give you a rough idea on how to do it. I am assuming you are new to PHP. I suggest you to read/learn a little bit first before asking for code.

Thanks

Comment: or you can send table cells with classes like open, close and write CSS as: 
.open{background-color:green;} .close{background-color:red;}

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this

Comment: _I suggest you to read/learn a little bit first before asking for code._ Really, why? Someone will almost always do it for them, removing the need to ever bother reading a manual or tutorial

Comment: @RiggsFolly I go to a tiny college I have been doing php for 3 years however I haven't learned about this kind of stuff. My college work on a "do it yourself" basis. I have been working on this since January. I couldn't find anything on my college system. I got so fed up of them not helping that I decided to ask here. I'm not just asking someone to do it for me I'm asking for an example so I can learn and improve. Please do not make assumptions purely because I asked a question.

Comment: @Laura There is a big _World Wide Web_ full of manuals, tutorials and a few of them are actually quite good. All of them will teach you something.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you think I haven't tried them? none of them had what I was specifically asking. I only asked a question don't comment rude things back. and make me out to be some lazy good for nothing who depends on others to do my work for me. I'm only trying to learn and improve. You were in my shoes once upon a time.

Comment: @laura you showed us __none__ of your tries. In this case everyone would think that you just want code. Please, as you're a new user, check [tour] and [mcve] to know what kind of questions can be asked here.